# MySQL Enums have non-intuitive behaviour, why?

Tags: mysql, enum

This very helpful article explains some oddities about **how MySQL Enums behave**: http://melp.nl/2009/05/mysql-enums-and-booleans/

There is no discussiong about **why** that behaviour exists. Furthermore, in googling the subject I find only contradictory information and speculation, by 'bloggers' and other blind leading the blind.

Can someone please describe **why** [MySQL Enums](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) suffer from the behaviour outlined in the post. Here is *one example* of Enum oddities presented in the post, but there are many more:

```
mysql> insert into t values('1'),('0');
mysql> select b,b=1,b=0 from t;
+---+-----+-----+
| b | b=1 | b=0 |
+---+-----+-----+
| 1 |   0 |   0 |
| 0 |   1 |   0 |
+---+-----+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Without explicitly telling what the problem is this question is not a good fit for the site, I guess.  Could you please outline it in a few sentences?  More detailed explanation could still be left for the article you linked.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have real booleans. It uses "C-Style" booleans where `0` means "false" anything else means true. So the "boolean" expression `b=1` returns a number - either `0` or `1` and that is then used as an index for the actual enum definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SELECT` in your example should be consistent with the `INSERT` with the way it uses quotes. The following works:

```
select b,b='1',b='0' from t;
```

[Here's proof](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e802b/3/0).

[MySQL's enum documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) explains that an enum is an **index** of **strings** - every entry has both a numeric index and a string value. The `SELECT` query in your question is using the numeric **index**, and the one I've provided is using the **strings** as you inserted them.

Also noted in the documentation are that the first value always has an index of 1, and that the index 0 always resolves to an empty string (''). An enum of `('0','1','3','Banana','2')` would therefore look like this:

```
Index = 'Value'
    0 = ''
    1 = '0'
    2 = '1'
    3 = '3'
    4 = 'Banana'
    5 = '2'
```

In the above example - as well as your original example - `select b,b=1,b=0 from t;` will look up the indexes 0 and 1, which resolve to the values `''` and `0` respectively.

You will almost never need to use the indexes when working with enum data - make sure you use the string values, and put quotes around them every time.

As a general rule, **don't use `enum` types to store numbers**. The risk of confusion is extremely high, and if you really want to restrict the values, there are other appropriate tools, such as lookup tables with foreign keys.

Comment: I think the reason why many people try to store numbers as enums is the lack of check constraints in MySQL. I see this very often as a workaround for that.

Comment: Thank you. Now it all makes sense: the author of that post, like most PHP devs (yes, I am among other things a PHP developer as well), does not understand datatypes. I'll be sure to pay special attention to this in the future. Thank you!